# Postgres - Add user information in metadata

Tags: postgresql

On Postgres meta data does not have user information. Is it possible to add user information on to metadata and if so how to achieve it.

Comment: Which "meta data" are you talking about?

Comment: Postgres metadata

Comment: Which metadata? Metadata about tables? Views? Other things?

Comment: Metadata when data insert, update and delete happens. Able to view schema information and need to find out which user is triggering those actions

Comment: That information is not stored by Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, So it is not possible to add user information on logs.

Comment: Which "logs"? The Postgres server log? Yes, you can add the user name to that. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT

Comment: Can user name could be added on wal2json

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a trigger for that. something like this could work: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger